# Materializecss 1.0.0 + Angular

Tags: angular, materialize

Has anyone successfully built any apps with Angular and latest version of Materializecss 1.0.0 (beta or rc)?
https://materializecss.com/

Seems like all the existing documentation is around Materializecss 0.100.2 or with v 1.0.0 but only javascript examples. I'm looking for an Angular (v6 preferably) solution, with typescript. Struggling to get this working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use the official angular material framework by google? https://material.angular.io/

Comment: Also an option @BkSantiago... but I was curious about working with MaterializeCss as well

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you need to do in order to use Materializecss with Angular2+

**1: Install from command line in your existing angular project:**

```
npm i materialize-css@next --save
```

**2: Include Materialize in your angular.json:**

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
        ]
```

**3: Start the server**

```
ng serve
```

**4: Start working**

I suggest download the example [template](https://materializecss.com/templates/parallax-template.zip) from official website and modify it to your needs.

**Important**
Once you've done the previous steps, you can use css components, but if you want to use the javascript capabilities, you need to declare an M variable of type any in each component you want to use them:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var M: any;

@Component({.....
```

**To initialize components, do something like this: (example for modal)**

```
this.myModal= new M.Modal(document.querySelector('#myModalId'), this.modalOptions);
```

Try to use ids instead of classess in this step, so you can have a better control and avoid conflicts